# the place of the phrase "in car production" is correct?

Tags: phrases, sentence-structure

> In which kind of processes are the large and complex robots used **in car production**?

In this sentence, is the place of the phrase **in car production** correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the phrase "in car production" can be confused with the verb "used".

Answer (score 1):

**In car production** is a **prepositional phrase** describing the location of your question and can be positioned in **various places** in the sentence **without loss of understanding**

> In which kind of processes are the large and complex robots used **in car production**?
>
> In which kind of processes **in car production** are the large and complex robots used?
>
> **In car production**, which kind of processes are the large and complex robots used?

Comment: The phrase *which kind of processes* caught my attention. I wouldn't judge whether it's grammatical or not, but this kind of pattern has been discussed several times (I think) both on ELL and EL&U. I remember one (because I was in a comment) of them: [grammar - "This type of element" or "This type of elements"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/245692/11482).